# Post Data to Elastic Search from a C++ program

Tags: c++, json, elasticsearch, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to post some JSON data to Elastic Search from a C++ program where i am executing the *cURL* command using *system*.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{      


    system("curl -XPOST \"http://localhost:9200/test/_doc\" -H \"Content-Type: 
    application/json\" -d\"{\"drop\" : 40, \"@timestamp\" : \"2020-05-20T03:05:30\"}\"");


    return 0;

}
```

It returns the following error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 1, column: 3]"}},"status":400}
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem as my *PUT* request is working.

```
system("curl -XPUT \"http://localhost:9200/test5\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d\"{}\"");
```

The Mapping is:

```
"mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "drop" : { "type":"long"},
            "@timestamp" : { 
                "type": "date",
                "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but curl is also a C library that you can use directly from your C++ programs. Have you considered using that? See [libcurl-easy](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not escaping the json string correctly in the system call. I think its the curl command or the shell capturing them?

What you end up sending to the server looks like `{drop : 40, @timestamp : 2020-05-20T03:05:30}` 
Note: there are no quotes around drop - exactly what the error message is telling you.

To fix try using a single quote around your json in the system call like

```
 system("curl -XPOST \"http://localhost:9200/test/_doc\" -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -d \'{\"drop\" : 40, \"@timestamp\" : \"2020-05-20T03:05:30\"}\'");
```

Comment: This would be much easier to write if you use raw string literals! `R"(curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/_doc" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"drop" : 40, "@timestamp" : "2020-05-20T03:05:30"}')"`. See [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).